# Meteor React.js Adding User Accounts Crashes Application

Tags: meteor, crash, meteor-react

I'm doing the Meteor React.js tutorial part 8 here:

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts

My application has been running perfectly up until this point. It crashes the moment I follow the first step in the tutorial which is to add the account packages by running the following command:

```
meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password
```

Upon doing this and attempting to run the project, the run fails and give me the following Error log:

```
C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7_1\npm\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7_1\npm\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Barry\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7_1\npm\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

What is causing this error to occur and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been 9 (recommended) releases to Meteor since the version that you're using, and a [lot of issues](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues?q=is%3Aissue+bcrypt+is%3Aclosed) have been resolved around using bcrypt specifically. Try updating your app to the latest version of Meteor (via `meteor update`), remove your applications `node_modules` directory, and run a new `meteor npm install`.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you. I just assumed my application was running on the latest version because I started it today. I'll try this solution and accept if it works.

Comment: The `meteor update` command isn't working. It just loads indefinitely.

Comment: Nevermind, it randomly loaded the last time I tried, thank you!